# IBM MobileFirst 6.3 Application Center console doesn't work with HTTPS protocol

Tags: https, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have installed  MobileFirst 6.3 server with Application Center.

Environment:

- CentOS 6.5
- DB2 10.1fp4
- WAS ND 8.5.5.4.

If I access Application Center console with HTTP protocol it works fine. But if I use HTTPS the console is unusable. There is an message in pink frame and login name changed to "unknown user".

> Server error. Contact the server administrator

Mobile devices cannot access Application center too with HTTPS. I could not find any error messages in log (SystemOut.log) related to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recently discovered defect, which was fixed in the last few days (January 2015).

To receive the fix, you'll need to log-in to [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/) (available to IBM customers and business partners) and download the latest available MobileFirst Platform 6.3 iFix.

You then need to re-install/update the Application Center installation.

This link may work: http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other+software/IBM+MobileFirst+Platform+Foundation&release=6.3.0.0&platform=All&function=all

Comment: I'm getting the same errors, so I installed the fix (it updated App Center to version Version: 6.3.0.00-20150404-1503), and it's still happening.  And once a single https App Center login fails, all other logins (http and https) fail.  Nothing in the logs, no clues.  Of course, https is now required for iOS app installs.  Restarting Tomcat doesn't fix it, I actually have to uninstall the WARs and re-install to fix it.  Perhaps something is getting corrupted somewhere.  Any suggestions?